# Lottie ReactJS doesn't play again

Tags: reactjs, lottie

Trying to animate lottie every time when my state changes.

But It doesn't trigger like below;

```
import Lottie from 'react-lottie'
const GeneralHeader = ({ headerData }) => {
  const basketRef = useRef(null)
  ....

  const basketOptions = {
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    animationData: basketAnimation,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice"
    }
  }
  ....
  useEffect(() => {
    basketRef.current.play()
  }, [cartlist])
  ...
  <Lottie 
   options={basketOptions}
   width={65}
   ref={basketRef}
  />
```

It should be triggered when my "cartlist" is changed.
But It doesn't animate again.

It works only one time (at beginning)

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Any reproducible example? Any Sandbox you can share? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Instead of using the useRef, I think you should use the **isStopped** property of lottie as shown in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lottie#usage)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to use as shown in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lottie#usage) for **isStopped** property.

```
import Lottie from 'react-lottie'
const GeneralHeader = ({ headerData }) => {
  const [stopped, setStopped] = useState(false)
  ....

  const basketOptions = {
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    animationData: basketAnimation,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice"
    }
  }
  ....
  useEffect(() => {
    setStopped(false)
  }, [cartlist])
  ...
  <Lottie 
   options={basketOptions}
   width={65}
   isStopped={stopped}
  />
```

---

**[SOLUTION]** I'm sorry. This first method will work if you set loop as "true" and stopped before setting isStopped as 'false'. It's because when we set isStopped value to 'false', it'll play but it's already end and it can't reset. I can't find similar solution in **react-lottie** but I found the solution in **lottie-web** which was used under the hood by **react-lottie**. Here is the [usage](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/web?id=usage) from lottie-web documentation.

```
import lottie from "lottie-web";
const GeneralHeader = ({ headerData }) => {
  let anim = ""
  ....

  useEffect(() => {
    anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: document.querySelector("#test"),
      animationData: basketAnimation,
      renderer: "svg", // "canvas", "html"
      loop: false, // boolean
      autoplay: true, // boolean
    });
  })
  
  useEffect(() => {
    anim.goToAndPlay(0)
  }, [cartlist])
  ...

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I tried, but didn't work. Because that code only stops the animation, It never starts it. (And I can't start it because that 'isstopped' method is for 'start stop players')

Comment: Actually, you can't start because isStopped will start where it stopped. I'm sorry for my mistake